# mongodb server keeps crashing down in every few days

Tags: mongodb

I have a site running in php/mongodb.
I don't have much knowledge of mongodb, and my MongoDB server keeps shutting down in every 3-4 days.

Output of `grep -i 'killed process' /var/log/syslog*`

```
    /var/log/syslog.1:Jan 25 00:17:25 web01 kernel: [669043.120836] Killed process 1110 (mongod) total-vm:11289440kB, anon-rss:1089872kB, file-rss:0kB
```

Here are the logs just before the last 3 crashed, in case it can help :

```
2016-12-23T10:51:47.786+0100 I COMMAND  [conn398] command dbname.webpages command: find { find: "webpages", filter: { permalink: "over-xxxxxxxxxx" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: IXSCAN { permalink: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:1 reslen:14218 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 1371ms
2016-12-23T10:51:48.377+0100 I WRITE    [conn391] remove dbname.webpages query: { content: null, title: null } ndeleted:0 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:3 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4, w: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 4 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 4 } } } 1097ms
2016-12-23T10:51:48.973+0100 I COMMAND  [conn391] command dbname.$cmd command: delete { delete: "webpages", writeConcern: { w: 1 }, ordered: true, deletes: [ { q: { content: null, title: null }, limit: 0 } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:40 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4, w: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 4 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 4 } } } protocol:op_query 1865ms
2016-12-23T10:51:51.808+0100 I COMMAND  [conn398] command dbname.webpages command: find { find: "webpages", filter: { permalink: "why-xxxxxxxxxx" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: IXSCAN { permalink: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:2 nreturned:1 reslen:11930 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } } } protocol:op_query 2785ms
2016-12-23T10:51:51.924+0100 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 60, after asserts: 110, after connections: 190, after extra_info: 260, after globalLock: 330, after locks: 480, after network: 540, after opcounters: 570, after opcountersRepl: 580, after storageEngine: 670, after tcmalloc: 690, after wiredTiger: 800, at end: 1130 }
2016-12-23T10:51:53.185+0100 I COMMAND  [conn395] command dbname.products.tag command: find { find: "products.tag", sort: { sequence: 1 }, filter: { publish.de: "1" } } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:14 nreturned:5 reslen:23730 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 30 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 15 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 15 } } } protocol:op_query 5706ms
2016-12-23T10:51:53.185+0100 I COMMAND  [conn391] command dbname.webpages command: find { find: "webpages", filter: { publish: true, $or: [ { url: "page_not_found" }, { url2.: "page_not_found" } ] }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:52 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:5 nreturned:0 reslen:126 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 3381ms
2016-12-23T10:51:56.083+0100 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 180, after asserts: 260, after connections: 330, after extra_info: 420, after globalLock: 470, after locks: 580, after network: 590, after opcounters: 600, after opcountersRepl: 600, after storageEngine: 650, after tcmalloc: 780, after wiredTiger: 930, at end: 1290 }
2016-12-23T10:51:57.489+0100 I COMMAND  [conn391] command dbname.webpages command: find { find: "webpages", filter: { permalink: "over-xxxxxxxxxx" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: IXSCAN { permalink: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:2 nreturned:1 reslen:14218 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } } } protocol:op_query 3143ms
2016-12-23T10:51:58.049+0100 I COMMAND  [conn384] command dbname.products.items command: find { find: "products.items", sort: { hot_order: 1 }, filter: { publish.en: "1", $or: [ { tags: "hot" }, { tags.en: "56aaef74c602a9407f000018" } ], category: ObjectId('4e1a68e909d046a620000004') } } planSummary: IXSCAN { category: 1 } keysExamined:37 docsExamined:37 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:27 nreturned:5 reslen:87608 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 56 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 28 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 28 } } } protocol:op_query 11547ms
2016-12-23T10:51:58.154+0100 I COMMAND  [conn401] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:178 locks:{} protocol:op_query 133ms
2016-12-23T10:51:59.206+0100 I COMMAND  [conn401] command admin.$cmd command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:179 locks:{} protocol:op_query 481ms
2016-12-23T10:52:00.402+0100 I COMMAND  [conn391] command dbname.webpages command: find { find: "webpages", filter: { permalink: "why-xxxxxxxxxx" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: IXSCAN { permalink: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1 nreturned:1 reslen:11930 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } } } protocol:op_query 1704ms
2016-12-23T10:52:00.443+0100 I COMMAND  [conn401] command admin.$cmd command: saslContinue { saslContinue: 1, conversationId: 1, payload: BinData(0, 633D626977732C723D64556248455541334E554651383166665A747650774A3469697053346A425744344143444677386A6A6C69554F5A4A597276575A732F33796532716775...) } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:108 locks:{} protocol:op_query 528ms
2016-12-23T10:52:01.072+0100 E QUERY    [js] Unknown Failure from JSInterpreter
2016-12-23T10:52:01.162+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:01.296+0100 I COMMAND  [conn401] command admin.$cmd command: saslContinue { saslContinue: 1, conversationId: 1, payload: BinData(0, ) } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:78 locks:{} protocol:op_query 168ms
2016-12-23T10:52:01.524+0100 I COMMAND  [conn395] command dbname.products.items command: find { find: "products.items", sort: { hot_order: 1 }, filter: { publish.de: "1", $or: [ { tags: "hot" }, { tags.de: "56aaef74c602a9407f000018" } ], category: ObjectId('4e1a68e909d046a620000004') } } planSummary: IXSCAN { category: 1 } keysExamined:37 docsExamined:37 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:14 nreturned:5 reslen:87608 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 30 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 15 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 15 } } } protocol:op_query 7526ms
2016-12-23T10:52:02.800+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:03.193+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:03.193+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:03.385+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:03.761+0100 E QUERY    [js] Unknown Failure from JSInterpreter
2016-12-23T10:52:03.761+0100 E QUERY    [js] Unknown Failure from JSInterpreter
2016-12-23T10:52:03.801+0100 I COMMAND  [conn398] command dbname.products.tag command: find { find: "products.tag", sort: { sequence: 1 }, filter: { publish.de: "1" } } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:13 nreturned:5 reslen:23730 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 28 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 14 } } } protocol:op_query 5558ms
2016-12-23T10:52:03.808+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:03.808+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:03.808+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:03.808+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:03.842+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:04.167+0100 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 20, after asserts: 40, after connections: 60, after extra_info: 100, after globalLock: 130, after locks: 180, after network: 220, after opcounters: 260, after opcountersRepl: 310, after storageEngine: 600, after tcmalloc: 690, after wiredTiger: 1390, at end: 1820 }
2016-12-23T10:52:04.661+0100 E QUERY    [js] Unknown Failure from JSInterpreter
2016-12-23T10:52:04.718+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:04.806+0100 E QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: out of memory
2016-12-23T10:52:04.806+0100 E QUERY    [js] Unknown Failure from JSInterpreter
2016-12-23T10:52:05.112+0100 F -        [js] Invalid access at address: 0
2016-12-23T10:52:05.433+0100 I COMMAND  [conn322] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""nl/promotiemateriaal-giveaways/tassen-bedrukken/katoenen-tas-bedrukken".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 exception: uncaught exception: out of memory code:139 numYields:1669 reslen:93 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 3342 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1671 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1671 } } } protocol:op_query 522720ms
2016-12-23T11:58:12.515+0100 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


2017-01-10T21:19:15.934+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52532] command admin.$cmd command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:179 locks:{} protocol:op_query 250ms
2017-01-10T21:19:16.325+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52270] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""de/schreib-notizbl-cke/schreibbl-cke-bedrucken".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12473 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:2277 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4556 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2278 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 2278 } } } protocol:op_query 81720ms
2017-01-10T21:19:16.570+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52538] command admin.$cmd command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:179 locks:{} protocol:op_query 392ms
2017-01-10T21:19:16.570+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52536] command admin.$cmd command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:179 locks:{} protocol:op_query 396ms
2017-01-10T21:19:16.570+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52537] command admin.$cmd command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:179 locks:{} protocol:op_query 396ms
2017-01-10T21:19:16.571+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52409] query dbname.system.js planSummary: EOF ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 3 } } } 112ms
2017-01-10T21:19:16.824+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52523] command dbname.$cmd command: listCollections { listCollections: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:1225 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { R: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 1089ms
2017-01-10T21:19:17.155+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52544] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { isMaster: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:178 locks:{} protocol:op_query 102ms
2017-01-10T21:19:17.972+0100 I COMMAND  [conn52542] command admin.$cmd command: saslContinue { saslContinue: 1, conversationId: 1, payload: BinData(0, 633D626977732C723D3131635035486E503037346C526C42426D4A674F646E425270464573446A5267713675767A5A6730476154464C704A494C3569754A30744C5551434831...) } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:108 locks:{} protocol:op_query 255ms
2017-01-11T09:09:06.733+0100 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


2017-01-17T06:12:24.835+0100 I COMMAND  [conn18620] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""be/kalender-bedrukken/bureaukalender-staand/bureaukalender-staand-medium".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12507 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:97 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 196 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 98 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 98 } } } protocol:op_query 839ms
2017-01-17T06:14:54.999+0100 I COMMAND  [conn18618] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""en/adhesive-notepads/post-it-notes/post-it-notes-smartline".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12507 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:97 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 196 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 98 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 98 } } } protocol:op_query 811ms
2017-01-17T06:15:34.798+0100 I COMMAND  [conn18638] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""de/notizb-cher/leuchtturm1917-bedrucken/leuchtturm1917-whitelines-link-notizbuch".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12507 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:98 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 198 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 99 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 99 } } } protocol:op_query 745ms
2017-01-17T06:20:34.937+0100 I COMMAND  [conn18475] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""en/notebooks/moleskine/moleskine-organizing-notebook".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12507 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:97 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 196 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 98 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 98 } } } protocol:op_query 788ms
2017-01-17T06:21:42.692+0100 I COMMAND  [conn18608] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""de/werbematerial-give-away/aufkleber-bedrucken/adressetiketten-mit-druck".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12507 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:98 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 198 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 99 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 99 } } } protocol:op_query 836ms
2017-01-17T06:22:48.255+0100 I COMMAND  [conn18475] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""de/werbematerial-give-away/taschen-bedrucken/non-woven-tasche-bunt".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12507 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:98 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 198 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 99 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 99 } } } protocol:op_query 758ms
2017-01-17T06:26:17.630+0100 I COMMAND  [conn18653] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""be/promotiemateriaal-giveaways/tablet-cases-bedrukken/ipad-mini-1-2-3-smart-case-light".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12507 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:97 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 196 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 98 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 98 } } } protocol:op_query 812ms
2017-01-17T06:26:30.897+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-01-17T06:26:30.897+0100 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2017-01-17T06:26:31.109+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2017-01-17T06:26:31.109+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-01-17T06:26:31.121+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2017-01-17T06:26:31.121+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2017-01-17T06:26:31.121+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-01-17T06:26:31.121+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-01-17T06:26:31.121+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-01-17T06:26:31.231+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2017-01-17T06:26:33.860+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2017-01-17T06:26:33.860+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
2017-01-17T06:26:58.446+0100 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


2017-01-25T00:17:20.589+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24812] command dbname.$cmd command: listCollections { listCollections: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:1225 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { R: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 606ms
2017-01-25T00:17:20.590+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24677] command dbname.products.tag command: find { find: "products.tag", sort: { sequence: 1 }, filter: { publish.en: "1" } } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1 nreturned:5 reslen:23730 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } } } protocol:op_query 8099ms
2017-01-25T00:17:20.864+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24771] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 1743ms
2017-01-25T00:17:21.555+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24641] command dbname.products.items command: find { find: "products.items", sort: { hot_order: 1 }, filter: { publish.de: "1", $or: [ { tags: "hot" }, { tags.de: "56aaef74c602a9407f000018" } ], category: ObjectId('4eb2301ec602a9ca10000004') } } planSummary: IXSCAN { category: 1 } keysExamined:33 docsExamined:33 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:3 nreturned:2 reslen:64963 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 8 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } } } protocol:op_query 9280ms
2017-01-25T00:17:21.555+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24734] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 4442ms
2017-01-25T00:17:22.298+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24816] command admin.$cmd command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:179 locks:{} protocol:op_query 394ms
2017-01-25T00:17:22.297+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24817] command admin.$cmd command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:179 locks:{} protocol:op_query 405ms
2017-01-25T00:17:22.297+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24818] command admin.$cmd command: saslStart { saslStart: 1, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1", payload: "xxx", autoAuthorize: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:179 locks:{} protocol:op_query 192ms
2017-01-25T00:17:22.284+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24497] command dbname.url_redirection command: find { find: "url_redirection", filter: { $where: ""en/adhesive-notepads/post-it-notes/post-it-name-pads".match("^"+this.old_url+".*")" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12559 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1902 nreturned:0 reslen:133 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 3806 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1903 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1903 } } } protocol:op_query 76237ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.441+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24675] query dbname.system.js planSummary: EOF ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } 822ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.445+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24720] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 4277ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.445+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24774] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 4275ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.445+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24810] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 3054ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.446+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24775] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 4269ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.446+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24799] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 4257ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.815+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24751] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 5234ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.817+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24740] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 3393ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.836+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24736] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 4572ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.837+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24800] command dbname.theme command: find { find: "theme", filter: {} } planSummary: EOF keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:123 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 4256ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.837+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24639] command dbname.webpages command: find { find: "webpages", filter: { permalink: "why-dbname" }, limit: 1 } planSummary: IXSCAN { permalink: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1 nreturned:1 reslen:11930 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } } } protocol:op_query 6314ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.838+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24668] command dbname.products.tag command: find { find: "products.tag", sort: { sequence: 1 }, filter: { publish.en: "1" } } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:5 reslen:23730 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 6196ms
2017-01-25T00:17:23.839+0100 I COMMAND  [conn24659] command dbname.products.tag command: find { find: "products.tag", sort: { sequence: 1 }, filter: { publish.de: "1" } } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:12 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1 nreturned:5 reslen:23730 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } } } protocol:op_query 7038ms
2017-01-25T06:21:31.552+0100 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
```

Following are the size details of the database : 
    Storage Size: 30.82m
    Data Size   : 70.22m
    Index Size : 2.64m
    Collections : 24
    Objects: 40205

Comment: Your queries are taking several seconds to run then you're out of memory.  How big is the collection and how is it laid out?  Do you have some process that scrapes everything at that hour?

Comment: Thnx.Just few hundred records, dont know about any process

Comment: @AliRazeghi Can you single out any specific query ?

Comment: @MohdQasim please edit your posting with the output of `grep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages*` thanks

Comment: grep: /var/log/messages*: No such file or directory

Comment: what says `top` and other Linux performance monitoring tools? For example `sar`, `iostat`, `dmesg` and `vmstat`? Do you use a traditional UNIX? Which OS and Version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, mongod: 2.3.9

Comment: @MohdQasim this one in particular took 11.5 seconds.  You can see the time taken at the end in ms, i have to cut it short but do a search for 11547ms:
dbname.products.items command: find { find: "products.items", sort: { hot_order: 1 }, filter: { publish.en: "1", $or: [ { tags: "hot" }, { tags.en: "56aaef74c602a9407f000018" } ], category: } 
....
protocol:op_query 11547ms

Comment: How big is your collection in megabytes, what hardware is it on, is it commodity hardware, and what are your performance metrics specifically RAM and disk io?

Comment: @ Sorry for later reply, updated the question to include details

Comment: @AliRazeghi Ram Size 2GB, can you please tell me what other information you need, also the above query runs fine